# Import tasks or playbooks with a boolean condition in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Effectively I need something like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
    
  tasks:
    - name: Perforce template
      import_tasks: ./../vsphere-client/perforce/template_to_vm.yml
      when: new_server_type == "perforce"
    
    - name: Gitlab Pgbouncer template
      import_tasks: ./../vsphere-client/gitlab-pgbouncer/template_to_vm.yml
      when: new_server_type == "gitlab-pgbouncer"
    
    - name: Gitlab Postgres template
      import_tasks: ./../vsphere-client/gitlab-postgres/template_to_vm.yml
      when: new_server_type == "gitlab-postgres"
    
    - name: Build API template
      import_tasks: ./../vsphere-client/build-api/template_to_vm.yml
      when: new_server_type == "build-api"
```

But it gives an error like:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <type 'bool'>
```

I understand this is not supported but is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There must be something else you are not showing because your code looks ok and should work. I suspect the problem is in the file you are importing.

Meanwhile, if it is not a problem to switch to `include_tasks`, you could greatly shorten the above with a single task:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: "{{ new_server_type }} template"
      include_tasks: "./../vsphere-client/{{ new_server_type }}/template_to_vm.yml"
```

If you really need a check to make sure `new_server_type` has a correct value, it is still possible.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
   allowed_types:
     - perforce
     - gitlab-pgbouncer
     - gitlab-postgres
     - build-api

  tasks:
    - name: "{{ new_server_type }} template"
      include_tasks: "./../vsphere-client/{{ new_server_type }}/template_to_vm.yml"
      when: new_server_type in allowed_types
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `include_tasks` ie. something like the following

```yaml
- include_tasks: setup-RedHat.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
```

So for you it would be like as follows

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Perforce template
      include_tasks: ./../vsphere-client/perforce/template_to_vm.yml
      when: new_server_type == "perforce"
```

Answer (score 2):

As both of the previous answers have already implied, the catch is `import_tasks` versus `include_tasks`. The [documentation for import_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html) says:

> Most keywords, including loops and conditionals, only applied to the imported tasks, not to this statement itself.
> If you need any of those to apply, use ansible.builtin.include_tasks instead.